# python concurrent ProcessPoolExecutor not working on Raspberry Pi (idle python 3.4.2)

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multi-processing in a share price machine learning application running on raspberry pi 3 (4 cores). Here is some code which illustrates the problem:

```
from concurrent import futures

def some_function(x):
    return x + 1

def main_function(some_list):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(some_function, some_list)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main_function([1, 2, 3]))
```

When I run this, I immediately get a message saying the process is still running, and asking whether I want to kill it. Whether or not I press 'ok', the programme does not produce any results, or errors.

Changing the ProcessPoolExecutor to ThreadPoolExecutor solves the problem and the programme delivers the generator object as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix you logic in the following way:

```
from concurrent import futures

def some_function(x):
    return x + 1

def main_function(some_list):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(some_function, some_list)

    return list(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main_function([1, 2, 3]))
```

The `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` returns a generator which needs to be consumed in order to retrieve the results. Your above logic will not iterate over it, you get your generator object printed and nothing more.

Comment: Many thanks. I understand that it returns a generator object, and ThreadPoolExecutor also returns a generator. However, the problem is not the value of what is returned, it is that the ProcessPoolExecutor doesn't return anything (even with your suggested edit), whereas ThreadPoolExecutor returns a generator (or on your edit, a list). I now believe it is a bug in Idle - the script runs properly in the terminal.

Comment: With my fix the script runs correctly on my terminal where beforehand was just printing the generator. Blind guess: try indenting the line `return list(results)` within the with statement. Does that help? One of the issues here is that the with statement might not be blocking the call letting Idle think the script has finished.

Comment: No, afraid not. It behaves as it should with geany / terminal, it is idle that seems to have the problem. thanks again